# Python post using requests not working

Tags: python, post, request

The following code doesn't throw any error. So I can't debug it. It just freezes somewhere in the middle. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests

url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FAIpQLSez9DyP2JxxLLVFNfbAuLIDXOhS5T-75wlAF9JsSohiGQVy5Q/formResponse'
form_data = {
'entry.1979182813': '123456',
'entry.516943837':'rsamuel15@alustudent.com',
'entry.2118286285':'Randriakotonjanahary',
'entry.1614196389':'Tolotra',
'draftResponse':[],
'pageHistory':0}
session = requests.Session()
user_agent = {'Referer':'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1FAIpQLSez9DyP2JxxLLVFNfbAuLIDXOhS5T-75wlAF9JsSohiGQVy5Q/viewform','User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"}
r = session.post(url, data=form_data, headers=user_agent)

print 'Done!!!';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the URL you're are trying to access has a problem. The form does not exist and the web request never returns, so your code just sits waiting for a response.

In general, you should use a timeout to prevent your code freezing due to remote server problems and then handle the error/exception accordingly.

For example, give the request 60 seconds to complete:

`session.post(url, data=form_data, headers=user_agent, timeout=60)`